# How do I allow separate env variables on a Monorepo for each project in Vercel?

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

I have a Gatsby Theme monorepo structured like this:

```
@username/gatsby-theme-supertheme
website-1-using-theme
website-2-using-theme
...
```

Each of these websites are very similar but each use different `.env.development` and `env.production` files that are determining how the project is built:

example:
`AIRTABLE_BASE_ID:app_xxxxxx`

This variable would control what base on a CRM to pull the data from.

I am trying to move this to Turborepo and using a Monorepo but I am hitting a wall on how to manage environment variables on Vercel.

Is deploying separate projects the only way? So ditching the Monorepo entirely?

Comment: You can create multiple env variables on vercel for multiple apps in your monorepo. For example, `WEB_1_AIRTABLE_BASE_ID:app_xxxxxx`, `WEB_2_AIRTABLE_BASE_ID:app_xxxxxx`, `WEB_3_AIRTABLE_BASE_ID:app_xxxxxx`, etc. Now your Turborepo apps will pick up only the matched environment variable from vercel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes deploying monorepos with different projects is the only way.

I've contacted Vercel support and they confirmed me that.

Leaving this here in case someone Google's it.